# Pdo select join from 2 tables

Tags: php, sql

so i have a query which works but i want to add a function were users can "pause"

```
$stmt212 = $db->prepare('SELECT * 
FROM websites w
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.username = w.owner
WHERE u.coins >= ? 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1');
$stmt212->execute( array('1') ) ;
$row212 = $stmt212->fetch();
```

this works but now i need to select from websites were live = 1 has well has the coins over 1 in the user table did try this

```
$stmt212 = $db->prepare('SELECT * 
FROM websites WHERE live = ?
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.username = w.owner
WHERE u.coins >= ? 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1');
$stmt212->execute( array('1','1') ) ;
$row212 = $stmt212->fetch();
```

but didnt work

Comment: Err `WHERE u.coins >= ?` but you are replacing the `?` with what looks like a `username` and not a number

Comment: sorry just edited

Comment: so the top select can be cut out just got to get the second one to work

Comment: Not sure what that query is doing wrong?

Comment: not showing any results at all. Just wanting it to grab a website from the website table were the user has more than 1 coin

Comment: just did a print_r and got PDOStatement Object ( [queryString] => SELECT * FROM websites WHERE w.owner IN (SELECT u.username FROM users u WHERE u.coins >= ? LIMIT 1) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 )

Comment: @nicholasdavies, perhaps sharing the table structure can help people to comprehend your queries easier..

Comment: the websites table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stmt212 = $db->prepare('SELECT * 
FROM websites
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.username = w.owner
WHERE u.coins >= ? 
AND live = ?
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 1');

$stmt212->execute( array('1','1') ) ;
$row212 = $stmt212->fetch();
```